# Video Copyright: Can I mix my videos to one video and copyright one time?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, is-x-legal

Suppose I have a large number of videos and I want to register the copyright on them so others can't copy them and use them.

Instead of paying for each registration alone, is it okay to mix all of them together as one big video and pay once for the registration for this big video, thereby protecting all of the separate videos?

Comment: This question is about registration of copyright. I think your question should be: "I want copyright registration on 100 of my original videos. Each video is 10 minutes long. To avoid having to pay 100 registration fees, can I concatenate all of the 10 minute videos into one long 16 hour video, and register that single 16 hour video compilation, and thus receive equivalent protection as if I had registered 100 individual copyright registrations on each of the individual 10 minute videos?"

Answer (score 2):

- **UPDATE:** My answer is about the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention), however the Berne Convention basically only applies outside the country of origin (Art. 5.3). The country of origin is the state where a work is first published (Art. 5.4). As you are from Lebanon, my answer would only apply [outside Lebanon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Berne_Convention_signatories.svg) if you first publish it in Lebanon. However if you first publish it in another country [which signed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Berne_Convention_signatories.svg) the Berne Convention, my answer would also apply to Lebanon, but possibly not to that other country.

If you mix your videos into one combined work, the result is copyrighted. But there is not reason to do so, because each separate video is also copyrighted. You don't need to register your works, neither do you need to pay a fee.

The wikipedia article about the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention) explains:

> The Berne Convention for the Protection of Literary and Artistic Works, usually known as the Berne Convention, is an international agreement governing copyright, which was first accepted in Berne, Switzerland, in 1886.
>
> The Berne Convention formally mandated several aspects of modern copyright law; it introduced the concept that a copyright exists the moment a work is "fixed", rather than requiring registration. It also enforces a requirement that countries recognize copyrights held by the citizens of all other parties to the convention.

[Lebanon joined](https://www.wipo.int/treaties/en/remarks.jsp?cnty_id=981C) the Berne Convention on September 30, 1947.

So the Berne Convention also applies to you. That means you have automatically copyright at the moment you create a video. You don't need to do anything to get the copyright.

Comment: If I shouldn't register my work then if someone steal the work, how do I proof that I am the owner of the work?

Comment: Copyright under Berne does not *require* registration, but many jurisdictions offer registration nevertheless. Not only does this make it easier to prove authorship, e.g. in the U.S. prior registration is also a prerequisite for collecting punitive damages from an infringer (only in the case of U.S. copyright – foreign copyright is not disadvantaged and never requires registration). No idea what the situation is in Lebanon, though.

Comment: @amon but if I had to register can I mix the 100 videos or 200 videos.....into 1 single big video and only pay once for registration...so that now individual videos are also copyrighted?

Comment: @data My comment was primarily addressed at  a misconception in an earlier version of this answer. I skimmed over the applicable Lebanese copyright law and saw that it lists fees for copyright depositions. But I can't tell you whether deposition of a collection of videos would also count as a deposition of the individual videos. In your place, I'd ask the deposition office for their policy on this.

Comment: @amon I want to know just from a legal point of view, If I had a video that I copyrighted.......then does it make sense that I am able to cut it into smaller videos by means of editing and still have the copyright for what ever cuts of video I make? example: originally I have a 2 hour video and I copyright this video then I can use lets say the first 5 min of the video....shouldn't this 5 min piece be copyrighted too?

Comment: @amon Under [17 USC 411(a)](https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap4.html) in the US no infringement lawsuit may be brought for a US-work unless the copyright was first registered. This does not apply to a non-US work, i.e. a work first published outside the US. However, under 17 USC 412 any "award of statutory damages or of attorney’s fees" requires registration, even for non-US works.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: I would think that an infringement lawsuit would also require that the material actually have been copied from the registered work or a work derived *from it*, and not from some other work.  If Bob publishes a short story, and later publishes and registers a collection containing it, I would think a copyright infringement lawsuit involving the story would require a showing that the material was copied from the collection, and not from the earlier published story.

Comment: @supercat Under US law you would be mistaken. US copyright lawsuits normally show merely exact or substantial similarity to the protected work, and does not show exactly what version was copied. If any version of the work was registered, that is enough (although registration after the act of infringement may not always confer the full benefits).  ... (continued)

Comment: The only time when the source version matters is if one version is unprotected. In particular if the work was published under the 1909 copyright act and lost protection through lack of a copyright notice, or by not being renewed, etc. Then anything in that version is in the public domain and may be copied freely. Only content new in the later version is protected. But even there if the copier used the later version but only took elements present in the PD version, there is no infringement.

Comment: If someone registers work X, and someone is accused of copyright infringement, the fact that the accused didn't have access to X nor any work which is directly or indirectly derived from X is a valid legal defense, even though it's not accepted as plausible *absent some showing of how one could have produced an identical work without access to X or a derivative*.  If X contains some previously-published but unregistered work Y, and the defendant's work contains no part of X that isn't in Y, then it becomes highly plausible that the defendant's content infringes upon non-registered Y, not X.

Comment: @DavidSiegel [see above] Although a defense based upon improper registration would hardly be guaranteed to succeed, I don't think a court would look kindly upon the fact that a plaintiff who had the opportunity to register the correct work declined to do so in the hope of avoiding registration fees.  Even a plaintiff would have a 90% chance of either having courts ignore the distinction between X and Y, or dismissing a case without prejudice to allow filing of the correct registration, it would seem much wiser to simply register the works properly in the first place.

Comment: @supercat  It used to be required in the US that the plaintiff prove access. Then there was a case where the proof of access fell down, and US courts held that proof of similarity was enough, with no evidence of access. i can find the case if you insist. When a work exists in many versions (such as software) it can be onerous to register every version, and courts do not demand it. I am not aware of a case defended on the grounds that the wrong version of a work was registered. In your hypothetical I think the defendants work infringes both X and Y and a court would so rule. Do you know a case?

Comment: @DavidSiegel: The fact that a work is more similar to a registered work than to anything which isn't derived from it would entitle a plaintiff to a *presumption* of access, but a defendant could counter that by showing how someone could produce the work in question without access to the registered work or anything derived from it, using instructions which would be sufficiently simple as to lack the level of creativity necessary to create a new copyrighted work (e.g. concatenate the first eight bars of public domain song X and the last eight bars of public domain song Y).

Comment: @supercat When a work can be derived from PD materiel, and contains nothing of the source that is not PD, it is not infringing at all, however it was created. But where the admitted source work is by the same author, and is protected, but not registered, I don't that such a claim would fly. If a work exists in several minor variations, I think it suffices to register the most recent, as this gives notice that the content is protected, and who holds rights. I will look for a case. Do you know of one on point?

Comment: @DavidSiegel: I don't know of any cases where someone has attempted to register an aggregation of previously-published works in lieu of registering the individual works, but I doubt that precedents exist that would fully cover all of the issues that would be posed by such action.  Some defendants prevail on the basis that the plaintiff failed to properly register the work in question, and the registration fee would seem a small expense compared with any extra litigation costs that might result if the defendant raises the issue.